# OAuth token parameter missing when configuring Google Analytics Reports

Tags: 7, google-analytics

I'm displaying Google Analytics reports at my site using Google Analytics Reports module which uses Oauth.

At the localhost on my computer it works fine.

But on a site my.example.com it is showing "OAuth token parameter missing" when I go to "admin/config/system/google-analytics-reports" and press "Start setup and authorize account".

I see this error in the watchdog:

> Code: 401 - Error: Unauthorized - Message:
>   GDataauthErrorAuthorizationInvalid Credentials

If I migrate my site from localhost to this site then also it works fine until I clear my cache.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The Linux server running my.example.com which was giving problem had time lag of 45 minutes. The moment I corrected it .. it worked.